# How to transfer information from GUI pyQt5 to another file

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to transfer the path of myfile from GUI written in PyQt5 to another python file for parsing, but I could not do what I expect.

I tried to use a global variable to solve my problem, now I found out in other post about using another file as a global variable. But it seems still does not work for me.

GUIfile.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp
from PyQt5  import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Parsefile import Something_here
import Setting
import Parsefile
     class Ui_MainWindow(object):
          def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
              MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
              MainWindow.resize(671, 506)
              self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
              self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
              self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
              self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 361, 201))
              self.label.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/newPrefix/UppaalIcon.PNG);")
              self.label.setText("")
              self.label.setObjectName("label")
              self.InputFilePmlBtu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
              self.InputFilePmlBtu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 300, 101, 23))
              self.InputFilePmlBtu.setObjectName("InputFilePmlBtu")
              self.InputFilePmlexBtu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
              self.InputFilePmlexBtu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 340, 101, 23))
              self.InputFilePmlexBtu.setObjectName("InputFilePmlexBtu")
              self.OutputPathBtu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
              self.OutputPathBtu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 390, 101, 23))
              self.OutputPathBtu.setObjectName("OutputPathBtu")
              self.lineEditInPutPml = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
              self.lineEditInPutPml.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 300, 431, 20))
              self.lineEditInPutPml.setObjectName("lineEditInPutPml")
              self.lineEditInPutPmlex = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
              self.lineEditInPutPmlex.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 340, 431, 20))
              self.lineEditInPutPmlex.setObjectName("lineEditInPutPmlex")
              self.OutPutPathUppaalFile = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
              self.OutPutPathUppaalFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 390, 431, 20))
              self.OutPutPathUppaalFile.setObjectName("OutPutPathUppaalFile")
              self.OkBtu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
              self.OkBtu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 430, 75, 23))
              self.OkBtu.setObjectName("OkBtu")
              self.CancelBtu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
              self.CancelBtu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 430, 75, 23))
              self.CancelBtu.setObjectName("CancelBtu")
              MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
              self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
              self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 671, 21))
              self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
              MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
              self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
              self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
              MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)




    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.InputFilePmlBtu.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input file Pml"))
    def PmlInputFile(self):

        Setting.filePmlName, _= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Select Pml File","","Pml File(s) (*.pml )")

        if Setting.filePmlName:  #  If the files is choosen by users.
                self.lineEditInPutPml.setText(Setting.filePmlName)  



import source

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Parsefile.py:

```
import Setting.filePmlName
filePath = Setting.
   def parse_file(filePath):
       with open(filePath, 'r') as file_object:
           #do sth here
   def Something_here():
```

Setting.py:

```
filePmlName=""
```

I would like when I run GUIfile and use it to choose a file. Hence its path return to Setting.filePmlName and this variable can transfer the file path to a variable filepath in Parsefile. However, it does not work as I expect, the variable filepath in Parsefile always ==""(as in Setting file, it seems that this variable does not update). Now when I run the GUI, choose the file and click OK the error always give me: FileNotFoundError: [Errn 2] No such file or directory.

I `print("filePath needed to translate= ",filePath)` (in Parsefile.py), and result is empty.

Comment: Is your problem to transfer a variable to another file?

Comment: Yes,  the variable Setting.filePmlName  will contain the path of the file which is chosen by the user from my GUI. I would like to transfer this information to a variable filepath in Parsefile.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code of yours is really difficult to read, please consider to follow the python writing conventions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. Also, I don't understand: what is `Setting` in GUIfile since you do not import it?

But still, if I get it right, why not simply pass the `filename` variable as an argument of the `parse_file` method? Something like:

parser.py

```
def parse_file(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'r') as file_object:
        parsed_file = ...
    return parsed_file
```

gui.py

```
import parser

class Ui_MainWindow():

    def processPmlInputFile(self):

        filename, _= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"Select Pml File","","Pml File(s) (*.pml )")

        if not filename:
            return

        parsed_file = parser.parse_file(filename)

        # ... do what you want with the result
```

Global variables, especially if they are not constants, could become really tricky.

But if you really want to use a global variable, i would advice you to use a dictionary, for example:

config.py

```
userdata = {'filename': ''}
```

script.py

```
stored_filename = config.userdata.get('filename', '')
```

Comment: my bad in the first file it needs to be imported Setting. Btw, Setting is the file containing a global variable. I will try your suggestion, but if I am not wrong, the complier will say filepath is not defined.

Comment: Where is it supposed to say it is not defined?